# AWS EC2 instance responds to DNS but doesn't allow RDP access nor ping

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, iis, dns, rdp

I have a EC2 Windows instance that used to work fine when accessing from RDP. I configured my website and everything but now when I try to access the machine from RDP i get a timeout everytime both using IP or the dns AWS provided.

The weird thing is, if I try to access my site (that is hosted in this instance) through the browser using both the site dns name or the server ip address it works fine.
But if I try to ping this dns or the ip address all the packages are lost.

Sadly I'm not experienced in dealing with network issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you allow access to the RDP ports on the Security Group?

EC2 -> NETWORK & SECURITY (On left side) -> Security Groups -> Select the one attached to your instance -> Allow the ports in the "Inbound" tab.

The port usually is 3389.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, that was a stupid question. I had set the RDP access to my local IP, my IP was changed and them BOOM! 

Well, I'm going to leave it here in case anyone else makes the same mistake. 
Valeu cara!